How to Prevent ?keyword Parameter from Being Indexed and Stop Its Generation in WordPress?
I need help with the following:-
1-Prevent ?keyword parameter from being indexed in search engines (Google Search Console).
2-Stop ?keyword parameter from being generated in WordPress.

Does this answer your question? How to Handle? vp_page Parameter in WordPress and Resolve Google Search Console Validation Issues?
